# Sqlite3 - UPDATE Column by Lookup

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to lookup and update Market_Sector column in Accounts from MarketSector in Clients. The key columns are Client in Accounts Table and Id in Clients in Table. I have written the below code, but the look up only returns None! Please help!

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('''C:\\Users\\Bank DB1.db''')
cur  = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE Accounts ADD Market_Sector''')
cur.execute('''UPDATE Accounts
            SET Market_Sector = (SELECT MarketSector FROM Clients
            WHERE Client = (SELECT Id FROM Clients))''')
con.commit()
con = sqlite3.connect('''C:\\Users\\Bank DB1.db''')
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Accounts''')
results = cur.fetchall()
print(results)
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliases for the tables so that the subquery is properly correlated:

```
UPDATE Accounts AS a
SET Market_Sector = (
  SELECT c.MarketSector 
  FROM Clients AS c
  WHERE c.Id = a.Client
)
```

Or with proper use of the table names:

```
UPDATE Accounts
SET Market_Sector = (
  SELECT Clients.MarketSector 
  FROM Clients
  WHERE Clients.Id = Accounts.Client
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am erroed - OperationalError: near "AS": syntax error

Comment: @Joy the query is syntactically correct, you can check it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=85ab9bb19d82f416e40f2738bfcafcdf I will post another one using that table names.

Comment: Thank you, my tables have the below columns

Comment: Accounts Table has AccountId, Client, Product, CCY & Balance
Clients Table has Id, Name, CtryResidence, Category, MarketSector and City
Client = Id

Comment: Big Thank you, it works with the table names! Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for educating me, I have accepted your solution by clicking on the tick sign.